# Execution failed for task ':react-native-community_netinfo:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I get this error while trying to make a build for android (eas build --platform all)

I have no clue of how to fix this error and I'm stuck here since days, anyone has seen this error? pasting some of the final errors I get from the build fail message, I don't know if it's related and I don't know where to look at... thank you in advance for your help!!

```html
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:162507:99: warning: the variable "Intl" was not declared in function "PluralResolver"
...atibilityJSON === 'v4') && (typeof Intl === 'undefined' || !Intl.PluralRul...
                                      ^~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:164862:18: warning: the variable "Buffer" was not declared in function "hotpDigestToToken"
    var digest = Buffer.from(hexDigest, 'hex');
                 ^~~~~~
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:168445:42: warning: the variable "Element" was not declared in function "equal 1#"
...f (hasElementType && a instanceof Element && b instanceof Element) return ...
                                     ^~~~~~~
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-community_netinfo:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
```